# How to open a view using a button

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I have a tabbed application, and I'm really new to xCode. I created a first view.

[image]

So I need help with code for the Quotes button to help lead me to the tab bar controller. Thanks

Comment: Despite the answers, it would be better to use a modal segue. Apple does not recommend embedding UITabBarControllers in UINavigationControllers, as it becomes confusing when a UIViewController for a given tab are themselves a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a programmatic ("custom") segue in the view controller. This probably isn't what you want.

In Interface Builder, select that segue and in the Attributes Inspector, change the kind of segue to "Show (e.g. Push)".

[image: Interface Builder]

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, do you mind explaining a little further, I'm new to xCode. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. If you navigate to your storyboard, find the segue, click on it, and then on your keyboard press Option+Command+4, you will reveal the Attribute Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like you're using a custom segue and it looks like you don't actually need it in your situation.

There is a simple solution by changing the segue `Kind` to `Show (e.g. push)`. This will simply show the connected view controller on top of your first viewcontroller.

This won't allow you to navigate back to the first view controller. If you want to do so, click on the first view controller in your storyboard and go to Editor > Embed in > Navigation controller.

This will automatically add a navigation controller which will manage the default navigation for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)   
let tb = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Storyboard ID") as! UITabBarController   
self.presentViewController(tb, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

To return from TabBarController

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

click on button press and hold control and drag it to another view controller some actions will pop than select the first option show and you are ready to go.